# Detect if a page is a variation page (done using Visual Website Optimizer's (VWO) "Split URL test")

Tags: web, redirect, optimization

How can we detect if a page is a redirected page (variation page of VWO's split url test) or not?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the cookie set by the VWO. In case it is a Split URL test, you can check for the cookie named _vis_opt_exp_TESTID_split which tells that the page was redirected by VWO. The cookie would be created first time you are being sent to the variation URL.